# How to add grid view values to datatable using for loops

Tags: c#

[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2Quv.png)how to add bunch of grid view values to datatable using for loops this is my code it does not worked.

```
for(int r=0; r<dataGridView1.Columns.Count; r++)
        {
            Dtbl.Columns.Add();
        }
        //Dtbl.Columns.Add("1");
        //Dtbl.Columns.Add("2");
        //Dtbl.Columns.Add("3");
        //Dtbl.Columns.Add("4");
        //Dtbl.Columns.Add("5");
        //Dtbl.Columns.Add("6");
        //Dtbl.Columns.Add("7");

        for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; x++)
        {
            for(int y =0; y<dataGridView1.Columns.Count; y++)
            {
              Dtbl.Rows[x].ItemArray[y] =  dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value;    //Dtbl.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: did you mean data base?

Comment: No only data Table

Comment: "It does not work" is the most useless debugging statement of all times. Add info about how exactly does it not work.

Comment: This looks like an incredibly confused bit of code.. if dtbl is empty or any of the rows have been added, this code will fall on its face..

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView`!! This is wrong and confusing and and bound to get wrong answers wasting everybody's time.. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple way.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    //add as many columns you want.
    dt.Columns.Add("YOUR COLUMN NAME");

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
    {
         DataRow dr;
         dr = dt.NewRow();
         //dr["xxx"] => replace 'xxx' with respective key for all dr.
         dr["date"] = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells[0].Text);
         //adding records to datatable one by one.
         dt.Rows.Add(dr);
     }
```

Alternative, to this:

```
DataTable GetDataTable(GridView dtg)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            // add the columns to the datatable            
            if (dtg.HeaderRow != null)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < dtg.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(dtg.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text);
                }
            }

            //  add each of the data rows to the table
            foreach (GridViewRow row in dtg.Rows)
            {
                DataRow dr;
                dr = dt.NewRow();

                for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = row.Cells[i].Text.Replace(" ", "");
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

avoiding for-loops:-

```
BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dgrid.DataSource;
DataTable dt= (DataTable) bs.DataSource;
```

should work.

Comment: i also try this way "dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Dtbl.Rows[x].ItemArray[0].ToString()" but i wanr that way

Comment: didn't worked? this is working. can share exact error with above code?

Comment: yes it's work but i want that way because i want add random columns values in each time

Comment: didn't get you. do you want to avoid forloops?

Comment: have you tried last sol? this : `BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dgrid.DataSource;
DataTable dt= (DataTable) bs.DataSource;`